# error launching moveitsetup assistant

Tags: ros, moveit, moveit-setup-assistant

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On launching move it setup assistant, I get an error message saying that the process has died. I have used

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-moveit

source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
```

to install and setup the environment. I have also used `sudo apt-get update`, unfortunately the error persists

```
amrith@amrith-ThinkPad-T420:~$ roslaunch moveit_setup_assistant setup_assistant.launch 
... logging to /home/amrith/.ros/log/273d2cf4-e20f-11e6-9bc2-0021cc4b3caa/roslaunch-amrith-ThinkPad-T420-6923.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://amrith-ThinkPad-T420:46293/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: indigo
 * /rosversion: 1.11.20

NODES
  /
    moveit_setup_assistant (moveit_setup_assistant/moveit_setup_assistant)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [6935]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 273d2cf4-e20f-11e6-9bc2-0021cc4b3caa
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [6948]
started core service [/rosout]
process[moveit_setup_assistant-2]: started with pid [6951]
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/moveit_setup_assistant/moveit_setup_assistant: error while loading shared libraries: libmoveit_robot_state_rviz_plugin_core.so.0.7.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
================================================================================REQUIRED process [moveit_setup_assistant-2] has died!
process has died [pid 6951, exit code 127, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/moveit_setup_assistant/moveit_setup_assistant __name:=moveit_setup_assistant __log:=/home/amrith/.ros/log/273d2cf4-e20f-11e6-9bc2-0021cc4b3caa/moveit_setup_assistant-2.log].
log file: /home/amrith/.ros/log/273d2cf4-e20f-11e6-9bc2-0021cc4b3caa/moveit_setup_assistant-2*.log
Initiating shutdown!
================================================================================
[moveit_setup_assistant-2] killing on exit
[rosout-1] killing on exit
[master] killing on exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252843/error-launching-moveitsetup-assistant/) by [motoman](https://answers.ros.org/users/28745/motoman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2017-01-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-24**:
can you please tell us how you installed ROS: I'm assuming from debs (ie: `apt-get install ..`)? And MoveIt? Also *only* using `apt-get`?

**Comment by [motoman](https://answers.ros.org/users/28745/motoman/) on 2017-01-24**:
yes ! I installed ROS using apt-get and also the moveit setup assistant using apt-get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Turns out the OP had an inconsistent MoveIt installation (ie: different versions of the binary packages).

After installing all MoveIt packages with the same versions, things started working as they should.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2